# how to access multiple database rows in array in php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$d=array();
$e=array;
```

I have two database columns:
    $row['count'];
    $row['total'];
//while loop ends

```
$array=array($d,$e);
print_r($array);
```

Table structure is following:

```
count   total
1         3
2         4
```

How can I display all records this outside the loop as it works fine inside the loop but outside it displays only the last record?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    $array[] = [$row['count'], $row['total'];
```

edit:

```
$d=array(); 
$e=array(); 
while($rw =mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) { 
    $d[] = $rw['count1']; 
    $e[] = $rw['total']; 
    $array[] = array($rw['count1'], $rw['total']); // don't need this
}
$array=array($d,$e); // or that
print_r($array);
```

Comment: i want to access it outside the while loop

Comment: $array[] = ($row['count'], $row['total']); it gives me error on this line as:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: You can access $array outside the while loop.

Comment: yes I know i can but am not getting the output.. i hv stored the rows in separate arrays but when i tried to access them outside the loop i get no output at all

Comment: $d=array();
$e=array();
while($rw =mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){

$d=$rw['count1'];
$e=$rw['total'];
    $array = array($rw['count1'], $rw['total']);
}
 
 $array=array($d,$e);
 print_r($array);

Comment: its works perfect inside the loop but outside the loop when i tried to access it... it displays only the last record..any one please help @recode

Comment: $array[] = array($rw['count1'], $rw['total']); removing this line of code makes sense but if i removes $array=array($d,$e); also then its displays only: array

Comment: There's an `or` and not an `and`

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
foreach($arr as $row)
    $my_arr[] = array($row['count']=>$row['total']);
```

Comment: May I know what is the reason..??

Comment: we can also thought that $arr be the result from the DB...right

Comment: Thts why iam asking him that what is the reason for that